# Primary monitor wont work when secondary is removed

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am trying to set up a tv as my primary monitor but once it gets passed the windows logo the screen goes black.  I then set up a dual monitor and changed the screen resolution on the tv to be lower and this brings the screen back.  I made it my primary monitor and then unplugged the secondary monitor.  Now the tv screen goes black and the only way to get my video back is to hook up the secondary model again.

Please help I am running windows XP

Comment: can you please re explain this a little better? more details

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.  The easiest may be to put the monitor on the other connector, restart, and start Windows in Safe Mode.  Then set the monitor resolution to what the TV can handle.